# Using boost signals without variadic templates

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals, icc

I was rather unpleasantly surprised to find out that Boost.Signals2 do not work with the Intel C++ Compiler due to the lack of adequate support for variadic templates. So my question is - how can I make do without them? Is there a way?

Comment: Looks like a wrong boost config. Boost emulates variadic templates internally if they're not available. Check your config, especially `BOOST_NO_CXX11_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES` which seems to be related.

Comment: What compiler version do you use?

Comment: @IgorR. Parallel Studio XE 2013 SP1 Update 3

Comment: Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013 SP1 Update 3 ships Intel C++ Compiler 14.0 which supports variadic templates as documented at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler. Which version of Boost are trying to build with Intel Compiler?

Comment: Also are you this on Windows, Linux or Mac?